# How to open a file directly from msSaveOrOpenBlob?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using IE 11 for web development. Now in javascript, I do  window.msSaveOrOpenBlob(fileBlob), a pop up shows on the button of the page with save and open option.

Now what I want to achieve is that perform click event on open so the file will be open automatically(without user click open).

Here is the case:

User click a link, it should open the associated file with whatever file reader that can open the file. PDF, will be adobe reader, word document will be opened in microsoft word.

Things still works when I click the open button from pop up. I just want to skip this manual click and do it in the code.

I've seen some webpage does this, but can't figure out myself. Need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, we can't control the "open or save" prompt using JavaScript. It is the browser behavior.

As a workaround, to the pdf file, I suggest you could try to use the [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) plugin to display the pdf file. To the Office documents, you could check the following article to use the Office Web Viewer to view the document.

[Office Web Viewer: View Office documents in a browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser/)

Besides, here is an article about [displaying (Show) Word, Excel, PowerPoint (PPT) and PDF files in browser web page in ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Show-Word-Excel-PowerPoint-PPT-and-PDF-files-in-browser-web-page-in-ASPNet.aspx), you can also refer to it.